# What is the justification for this derivation?

Tags: calculus

In the book "probability theory: the logic of science", the following "derivation" is made:

Given the following assumptions:

> $$v= F(y,z)$$ Where $v, y, z$ are Real numbers. The partial derivatives of $F$:$$F_1(y,z) = \frac {H(v)}{H(y)}$$ $$F_2(y,z) = \frac
>  {H(v)}{H(z)}$$

The book uses the following steps:

> $$dv = dF(y,z)=F_1dy+F_2dz$$ $$\frac {dv}{H(v)}=\frac{dy}{H(y)}+\frac
>  {dz}{H(z)}$$

And uses this to derive the following equation:
$$\int^v\frac{dx}{H(x)} = \int^y\frac{dx}{H(x)}+\int^z\frac{dx}{H(x)}$$

**My question is: What is the justification for this? It seems to me like a bit of handwaving.**

- **For example, what is the justification for having the $v, y,$ and $z$ as the upper bounds of the integrals?**
- **Why are there no lower bounds?**
- **And more generally, how is this conclusion justified in the first place, since the middle two steps are strictly speaking not meaningful?**

Comment: And where did that $r$ come from in the last displayed equation? Are $F_1, F_2$ and $F$ supposed to be related in some way? Is $F_1$ perhaps the partial derivative of $F$ wrt the first variable? What's the codomain of $F$?

Comment: sorry about the $r$. yes $F_1$ and $F_2$ are partial derivatives wrt to the first and second variables, sorry. The Domain and Codomain are the real numbers.